PHP: Does move_uploaded_file() actually work with the S3 Stream Wrapper?
The Amazon S3 stream wrapper "enables you to store and retrieve data from Amazon S3 using built-in PHP functions, such as file_get_contents, fopen, copy, rename, unlink, mkdir, and rmdir. ... This enables you to access buckets and objects stored in Amazon S3 using the s3:// protocol. The Amazon S3 stream wrapper accepts strings that contain a bucket name followed by a forward slash and an optional object key or prefix: s3://bucket[/key-or-prefix]."
Notice that the function list does not include move_uploaded_file. I'm modifying some existing code to support S3, and the existing code uses move_uploaded_file to move an uploaded file to its permanent location. I have not changed that code; I'm merely supplying s3://my-bucket/file-key as the to argument of move_uploaded_file. (So the call is something like move_uploaded_file("/tmp/phpQ6IijD","s3://my-bucket/cabbc0ad015b8a7038925ae4b4a6335e").
move_uploaded_file is supposed to return true on success and false if the from argument is not a valid upload file or cannot be moved for some reason. move_uploaded_file("/tmp/phpQ6IijD","s3://my-bucket/cabbc0ad015b8a7038925ae4b4a6335e") returns true. I checked the /tmp directory. The file isn't there. Yet the file isn't in my S3 bucket either. So it looks like move_uploaded_file returned a false positive and perhaps also that the S3 stream wrapper doesn't apply to move_uploaded_file. I also checked the folder where the code resides to see if the file was renamed to "s3://my-bucket/cabbc0ad015b8a7038925ae4b4a6335e" and that apparently was not the case either.
What is actually happening here? Does the S3 stream wrapper not apply to move_uploaded_file? If not, what is the minimal code needed to replace it?

How does this not make sense? This is literally the situation I'm facing. I did not choose to use move_uploaded_file; it's already in the code that I need to adapt to use S3.

I don't have an answer to your specific question, but I am seeing an open issue related to Flysystem as well as an open PR that appears to be solving the general problem, so it looks like it is buggy for that scenario.

A simpler approach, which wouldn't trigger this or a similar bug, would be to call move_uploaded_file() with a temporary path on the same filesystem as PHP's temp dir. This means that the "move" is just a rename, not a copy. Then put it in S3 and remove the temp file.
